# How to redirect from old domain to new domain on nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I currently have a domain https://dongyhuynhtantrieu.com and now I want to convert it to https://bacsicare.com, how do I do it? I'm currently using wordpress and nginx. I tried the code but it didn't work.

```
server {    
server_name www.example.com;    
rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
```

}

Comment: That `server` block only handles your `http` requests, but your question is looking for an `https` redirection. You will need a `server` block with `listen 443 ssl;` statement and the `ssl_certificate` statements for the old domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **return**:

```
server {
    listen 80;    
    server_name old_domain.com www.old_domain.com;    
    return 301 http://new_domain.com$request_uri?; 
}
```

Or **if** inside server block:

```
if ($request_uri  =  / )  {
      rewrite (.*) http://new_domain.com/ permanent;
  }
```

Comment: I tried 2 methods above. For the first method, it only redirects to the home page. For the article, there is a ssl error. I have sent an attached image.
The same for the second method, but the posts do not make redirects.

Look forward to the help. Thank you!
image: https://imgur.com/TiFlJjx

Comment: @BlogiHuongDan this error means that domain name in your ssl cert doesn't match domain name in your nginx config.